# Random word generator with a equal probability of occurrence of letters

Tags: c#, random, probability

So I made a pretty simple word generator program in c# that works relatively well. My question is how to generate a words with a equal probability of occurrence of letters eg. aaaa, aabb or abab

My code:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();

        int num_letters = 4;
        int num_words = 20;

      char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

       Random rand = new Random();

         for (int i = 1; i <= num_words; i++)
        {
           string word = "";
            for (int j = 1; j <= num_letters; j++)
            {
                int letter_num = rand.Next(0, letters.Length - 1);

               word += letters[letter_num];
            }

             listView1.Items.Add(word);
```

Comment: You appear to have done so. I don't understand what you're asking; you've already written the code to do what you want.

Comment: Also, I note that the `ToCharArray` is unnecessary. Your program would work just as well without it; `letters` can be a `string`.

Comment: I want the generated words to consist of letters of the same probability

Comment: What makes you think they're not equally probable right now?

Comment: In your program they do! You've already got what you want. Every letter in the word has an equal 1/26 chance of being any letter in the alphabet.

Comment: What about what you've written makes you believe it is not doing what you want?

Comment: This program generate eg. HJYY and this is not equal probability.

Comment: Equal probability doesn't mean "no duplicates" if that's what you're getting at. The same way flipping a coin and getting Heads followed by another Heads doesn't mean there's not a 50% chance of getting Heads or Tails.

Comment: Sure it is. There are 456976 possible words, and HJYY is one of them, and it will be generated one time in 456976 attempts, on average. Just like AAAA will be generated one time in 456976 and OOPS will be generated one time in 456976 and GOAT will be generated one time in 456976 and so on.

Comment: Sure it is.  Flip a coin.  Flip it again.  Both heads?  Both tails?  One of each?  Doesn't matter - the third time you flip the coin, it has the same probability of coming up heads (1 in 2) or tails (1 in 2), no matter what they were the first two times.

Comment: I want the letters in the generated word to be with the same probability

Comment: Apparently your definition of those words are different than the standard definitions, because *you already have that*. So, let's try to disabuse you of your bad definition. Can you give a *clear and precise* definition of what you mean by "with the same probability"? Then we can tell you where you have gone wrong in your beliefs about probability.

Comment: You've said the same thing 3 times now and we keep telling you that that's the way it already is. You either need to change your understanding of what's going on or change what you're saying to something that actually reflects what you want.

Comment: Word = 4 Letters = probability -> 25% or 50% or 100% eg. aaaa (probability of letter = 100%) aabb (50%) abcd (25%)

Comment: You're saying that you want to generate a word where all the letters are different?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for the percentage of the word that consists of a given letter. 50% of "aabc" is made up of the letter a. 25% of it is made up of the letters b or c. Is that right?

Comment: For what it is worth, this would typically described as "Generate a four-lettered random permutation with no repetition from the letters A-Z"

Comment: @Mitch: I think the original poster does not understand that percentages and probabilities are two different things.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What's wrong with what you've written here?

Comment: Are you asking how to guarantee no duplicates?

Comment: It sounds like you may be falling victim to the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). The fact that you just generated, for example, an H doesn't mean that the next letter is any less likely to be an H - the probability is still 1 in 26. See also the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - the probability of duplicates is much higher than you'd think. If you can edit to clarify whether that's what you're asking, I'd be glad to vote to reopen. (In fact, I'd rather like to write an answer to that effect :) ).

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a round about way of asking for the factors of the word length. If you ignore the terms probability and percentage, it boils down to this: a letter must appear the same number of times as the other letters in the word (if any). Using OP's examples: "aaaa" -> 1 letter appears 4 times, "aabb" -> 2 letters appear 2 times, "abcd" -> 4 letters appear 1 time. Picking a random letter to represent the one factor seems secondary.

Comment: OP, you are using he wrong word to describe what you want. "Probability" means "chance of occurence". What you are asking for is an equal **frequency**, which means "the amount of times it occurs". While it is true that in **large** data sets, the probability and frequency tends to be **roughly equal** (as probability tends to describe "expected frequency"), **this is not guaranteed**. It's not impossible to roll a die 10 times and get a 6 every single time. You would _expect_ rolling a six to happen 1 times out of 6 because of the 1 in 6 probability; but the probability is just a prediction!

Answer (score 4):

This question is extremely confusing.

If what you're asking is how to generate a four letter word where every letter is different, you could do that like this:

```
string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string word = new string(letters.OrderBy(x=>random.NextDouble()).Take(4).ToArray());
```

Not the most efficient way to do it, but quick and easy to write.

UPDATE: I have finally figured out what thing the original poster is asking for.  They want strings of four characters that have the property that one of the following is true:

- The four characters are the same
- Two different characters each appear twice
- All four characters are different

That's easy enough. Two possible algorithms:

- Pick at random from the following possibilities: "0000", "0011", "0101", "0110", "1001", "1010", "1100", "0123", with whatever distribution you see fit. Then pick four random distinct letters, by the algorithm I give above.  Then search-and-replace the pattern string so that you replace zero with the first character in the random string, one with the second, and so on.
- Do rejection:

---

```
string word = null;
while(true) 
{
  word = GenerateRandomWord(); 
  if (AllFourAreDifferent(word)) return word;
  if (AllFourAreTheSame(word)) return word;
  if (TwoAndTwo(word)) return word;
}
```

Now all you have to do is implement those four helper methods, each of which is easy.

---

What made this question so confusing is that the original poster seems to not understand that percentages and probabilities are not the same thing.  The question should have been "How do I generate random strings which have the property that every distinct character of the string consumes the same fraction of the string as every other character in the string?"  This is *very* different than every character occurring with the same *probability*.

Comment: How should this look in my code?

Comment: Does this mean that the result of `x => random.NextDouble()` is cached for the `orderby` ?

Comment: @user5734658: You have plenty of hints here from which to construct a working program.

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel: Yes!

Comment: `This is very different than every character occurring with the same probability.` Imo, it's not as different as you make it seem, linguistically speaking. Probability is a description of _expected frequency_. Saying that you have a 50% chance to get heads, is actually saying that _in large data sets, heads tends to occur about half of the time_. However, OP is failing to see that there is a difference between _expected_ frequency (probability), and the _resulting_ frequency (actually flipping the coin and noting the result)